# Apache subfolder route not working with zf2

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, zend-framework2, apache2

I have one zf2 application and one wordpress blog, both are different directories. (/var/www/zf2 , /var/www/blog). I want that my route  example.com should point to my zf2 application and example.com/blog should point to my wordpress blog. I am using apache alias feature and it is working only for main route. example.com/blog is pointing to my wordpress blog but any other route of blog is pointing to zf2 application. Like example.com/blog/aboutus is pointing to my zf2 application and showing zf2 not found error page instead it should point to my blog page.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/zf2/public
     Alias /blog/ /var/www/blog/
     <Directory /var/www/blog>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        #Allow from all
     </Directory>
     <Directory /var/www/zf2/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please find below , htaccess content of my zf2 application.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

And these are my blog htaccess configuration.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Why would you not put the blog on it's own (sub-)domain and save this hassle of intermixing pathing of 2 applications, but not really? (e.g. what's going to happen when someone creates a `/blog` route in your ZF app in the future? And don't say it'll never happen, cause it just might and you'll have no idea what's going on (or that someone will not))

Comment: @rkeet Yes, I did the subdomain thing in past and now I want to move to subfolder, do you know how it can be done ?

Comment: why you need to use alias, why you didn't put that blog folder under zf2/public/blog ...